# Can we say '' a proof of my ...'' instead of ''a proof of myself being...''

Tags: grammar, phrasing

I have a question regarding A PROOF OF MY, as opposed to A PROOF OF MYSELF/MINE. The context is formal work email, and I was just wondering if it is proper use of an english saying/turn of phrase, or was this a sort of anomaly coming from English being a secondary language to me. In short, the sentence in context would sound something of the sort:

*Here is down below a proof of my being a worker in ... field.*

My concern stems from finding **Myself**, a bit informal or to simplistic wording for the context, and **Mine** being sort of 'childish'. And I really think I heard, or read some text with this specific way of phrasing things, but maybe it is my imagination. Please feel free to respond, as extensively as you want, or to phrase things in a very simple manner, all answers are welcomed.

Comment: Best answered on English Language Learners site. Briefly,  “My” is a possessive adjective requiring a following noun or gerund. It cannot be used as an adjectival noun. So you may refer to “my qualifications” (noun) and  you may refer correctly to “my being …” because being is a gerund.

Comment: Not only _can_ you but you _should_. The reflexive 'myself' is used far too frequently and usually incorrectly.